# jQuery click event does not work when fullscreen iframe in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-1.9

jQuery click event won't fire when there is a fullscreen iframe in the background :

JS :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(document).click(function(){
        if ($(this).find('.overlay').is(':visible')) {
            $('.overlay').hide();
        } else {
            $('.overlay').show();
        }
    });

});
```

HTML :

```
<body>

    <div class="overlay">Overlay</div>

    <iframe src="iframe.html" name="frame" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:100%; height:100%"></iframe>

</body>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color: green;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

I want to hide/ toggle the green box when then the click is occurred **outside** the box.

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an iframe, `.contents()` can be used :

[**Demo**](http://ataredo.com/external/demo/iframe-contents/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('[name="frame"]').on('load', function() {

        $(this).contents().click(function() {

        if ($('.overlay').is(':visible')) $('.overlay').hide();
        else $('.overlay').show();
        });
    });
});
```

> The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

https://api.jquery.com/contents/

If the content is on another domain, the only option would probably be to put an element on top of it.

Edit - code adjusted, it's important to wait for the iframe to load before applying the event handler...

Comment: Chose the quick select from Codepen which is version 2.1.3 but it was introduced in 1.2 already.

Comment: Edited the answer - waiting for the iframe to load before attaching a handler.

Comment: Cheers, made a local demo instead to debug. Wasn't easy to do on Codepen in this case...

Answer (score 0):

If the event is about that div (overlay) you should add listenner in overlay class with jquery, try these example and tell about the results

```
$(".overlay").click(function (){
 $(this).slideToggle();
}):
```

or

```
$(".overlay").click(function (){
 if($(this).hassClass('hide')){
  return $(this).removeClass('hide');
 }
 return $(this).addClass('hide');
});
```

css

```
 .hide{
    display:none;
    }
```

Comment: i want the click outside the .overlay - not inside/ on it.